# Iterate using Object key and findIndex failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
{
  "June": [
    {
      "id": "59361b2fa413468484fc41d29d5",      
      "is_new": false,
      "name":"John"
      "updated_at": "2017-06-07 10:52:05",
    }
  ]
}
```

I have above object and within it it has array of object, I tried to check within 'June', is there any is_new, but failed?

```
const has_any_is_new = Object.keys(arr).map(obj => 
    arr[obj].map(obj2 => obj2.findIndex(o => o.is_new) > -1)
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Comment: you forgot a comma after the `name` property. And you could remove the comma after `updated_at` as well.

Comment: Instead of using `findIndex(…) > -1`, you should just do `some(…)`

Comment: What exactly failed? What's the expected result, and what did you get instead?

Comment: Next time please click `<>` and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test whether any of the items in the June array has `is_new==true`, you can use `.some`:

```js
let months = {
  "June" : [
    {
      "id": "59361b2fa413468484fc41d29d5",      
      "is_new": false,
      "name":"John",
      "updated_at": "2017-06-07 10:52:05",
    },
     {
      "id": "59361b2fa413468484fc41d29d6",      
      "is_new": true,
      "name":"John2",
      "updated_at": "2017-06-07 10:52:05",
    }
  ]
}

const has_any_is_new = Object.keys(months).some( month => 
    months[month].some( obj => obj.is_new )
);

console.log(has_any_is_new)
```

`.map` just runs a function against each element in an array.

`.some` returns true if any of the functions it applies returns true.

Comment: some is just return true or false right? the comparison is similar to filter, just that filter return the array, am I right?

Comment: Yep that's correct. See [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score -1):

You have one `map` too much. `arr[obj]` already refers to the "June" array of objects, so `obj2` has the `.is_new` property but no `map` method. Use

```
const obj = { "June": […] };
const news = Object.keys(obj).map(key => 
    [key, obj[key].some(o => o.is_new)]
); // an array of month-boolean-tuples
```

or

```
const has_any_is_new = Object.keys(obj).some(key => 
    obj[key].some(o => o.is_new)
); // a boolean whether any month has a new entry
```